# Invalid image metadata when try to display a livephoto with PHLivePhotoView objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, phlivephoto

I am trying to load a `jpg` image together with a `mov` file with objective-c on ios device to display a live photo, and I make following code snippet to do that in `viewDidLoad` function:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PHLivePhotoView *photoView = [[PHLivePhotoView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

    NSURL *imageUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"livePhoto" withExtension:@"jpg"];
    NSURL *videoUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"livePhoto" withExtension:@"mov"];

    [PHLivePhoto requestLivePhotoWithResourceFileURLs:@[videoUrl, imageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"livePhoto.jpg"] targetSize:self.view.bounds.size contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit resultHandler:^(PHLivePhoto *livePhoto, NSDictionary *info){
        NSLog(@"we are in handler");
        photoView.livePhoto = livePhoto;
        photoView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        photoView.tag = 87;
        [self.view addSubview:photoView];
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:photoView];
    }];


}
```

I have drag the file `livePhoto.jpg` and `livePhoto.mov` to Xcode project

But when build this Xcode log this error:

```
2017-11-28 17:46:08.568455+0800 Live Photos[3669:1276778] we are in handler
2017-11-28 17:46:08.580439+0800 Live Photos[3669:1276778] we are in handler
2017-11-28 17:46:08.597147+0800 Live Photos[3669:1276806] Error: Invalid image metadata
2017-11-28 17:46:08.607881+0800 Live Photos[3669:1276806] Error: Invalid video metadata
2017-11-28 17:46:08.608329+0800 Live Photos[3669:1276778] we are in handler
```

Any idea about that? Thanks.

And another thing to ask:

Why does the `resultHandler` was called twice according to what is printed?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

Here's the code to store Live Photos and upload them to a server:

1. Capturing Live Photo

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCapturePhotoOutput *)output didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)photoSampleBuffer previewPhotoSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)previewPhotoSampleBuffer resolvedSettings:(AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings *)resolvedSettings bracketSettings:(AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings *)bracketSettings error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        [self raiseError:error];
        return;
    }
    NSData *imageData = [AVCapturePhotoOutput JPEGPhotoDataRepresentationForJPEGSampleBuffer:photoSampleBuffer previewPhotoSampleBuffer:previewPhotoSampleBuffer];
    CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    [self.expectedAsset addInput:image.properties]; // 1. This is the metadata (which will be lost in step 2.)
    [self.expectedAsset addInput:[UIImage imageWithCIImage:image]]; // 2. Creating image, but UIImage is not designed to contain the required metadata
}
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCapturePhotoOutput *)output 
didFinishProcessingLivePhotoToMovieFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL duration:(CMTime)duration photoDisplayTime:(CMTime)photoDisplayTime resolvedSettings:(AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings *)resolvedSettings error:(nullable NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        [self raiseError:error];
    } else {
        [self.expectedAsset addInput:outputFileURL]; // 3. Store the URL to the actual video file
    }
}
```

`expectedAsset` is just an object holding all required information. You can use a NSDictionary instead. And since this code snippet is a >= iOS 11 API, heres the one for "deprecated" iOS...

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunguarded-availability"
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCapturePhotoOutput *)output didFinishProcessingPhoto:(AVCapturePhoto *)photo error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        [self raiseError:error];
    } else {
        [self.expectedAsset addInput:[photo metadata]];
        [self.expectedAsset addInput:[UIImage imageWithData:[photo fileDataRepresentation]]];
    }
}
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

2.  Generate NSData

```
- (NSData*)imageData {
        NSData *jpgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 1); // This is the UIImage (without metadata) from step 2 above
        CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef) jpgData, NULL);
        NSMutableData *dest_data = [NSMutableData data];
        CFStringRef uti = CGImageSourceGetType(source);
        NSMutableDictionary *maker = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [maker setObject:[self.imageMetadata objectForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyMakerAppleDictionary] forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyMakerAppleDictionary];    // imageMetadata is the dictionary form step 1 above
        CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)dest_data,uti,1,NULL);
        CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination, source , 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) maker);
        CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
        return dest_data;
    }

- (void)dataRepresentation:(DataRepresentationLoaded)callback {
    callback(@{@"image": self.imageData, @"video": [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.livePhotoURL]}); // LivePhotoURL is the url from step 3 above
}
```

**Long Answer**

This is caused by wrong Metadata in the video/image file.
When creating a live photo, PHLivePhoto searches for the key 17 in `kCGImagePropertyMakerAppleDictionary` (which is the asset identifier) and matches this with the `com.apple.quicktime.content.identifier` of the mov file. The mov file also needs to have an entry for the time where the still image was captured (`com.apple.quicktime.still-image-time`).

Make sure your files haven't been edited (or exported) somewhere. Event the UIImageJPEGRepresentation function will remove this data from the image.

Here's a code snippet I'm using to convert the UIImage to NSData:

```
- (NSData*)imageData {
    NSData *jpgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 1);
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef) jpgData, NULL);
    NSMutableData *dest_data = [NSMutableData data];
    CFStringRef uti = CGImageSourceGetType(source);
    NSMutableDictionary *maker = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [maker setObject:[self.imageMetadata objectForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyMakerAppleDictionary] forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyMakerAppleDictionary];
    CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)dest_data,uti,1,NULL);
    CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination, source , 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) maker);
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
    return dest_data;
}
```

The Handler gets called twice to first tell you about corrupt data, and the second time about the cancellation of the process (these are two different keys).

EDIT:

Here's your mov data:

```
    $ ffmpeg -i cf70b7de66bd89654967aeef1d557816.mov
    Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: qt  
        creation_time   : 2018-01-27T11:07:38.000000Z
        com.apple.quicktime.content.identifier: cf70b7de66bd89654967aeef1d557816
      Duration: 00:00:15.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1189 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 540x960, 1051 kb/s, 29.84 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2018-01-27T11:07:38.000000Z
          handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
          encoder         : 'avc1'
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2018-01-27T11:07:38.000000Z
          handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
```

The `com.apple.quicktime.still-image-time` key is missing here.

Here's the metadata how it should look like:

```
    Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: qt  
        creation_time   : 2017-12-15T12:41:00.000000Z
        com.apple.quicktime.content.identifier: 89CB44DA-D129-43F3-A0BC-2C980767B810
        com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709: +51.5117+007.4668+086.000/
        com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
        com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone X
        com.apple.quicktime.software: 11.1.2
        com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2017-12-15T13:41:00+0100
      Duration: 00:00:01.63, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8902 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m/smpte432/bt709), 1440x1080, 8135 kb/s, 26.94 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          rotate          : 90
          creation_time   : 2017-12-15T12:41:00.000000Z
          handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
          encoder         : H.264
        Side data:
          displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: pcm_s16le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-12-15T12:41:00.000000Z
          handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
        Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 12 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-12-15T12:41:00.000000Z
          handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
        Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 43 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-12-15T12:41:00.000000Z
          handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
```

And just FYI, heres your JPEG Data:

```
    $ magick identify -format %[EXIF:*] cf70b7de66bd89654967aeef1d557816.jpg
    exif:ColorSpace=1
    exif:ExifImageLength=960
    exif:ExifImageWidth=540
    exif:ExifOffset=26
    exif:MakerNote=65, 112, 112, 108, 101, 32, 105, 79, 83, 0, 0, 1, 77, 77, 0, 1, 0, 17, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 99, 102, 55, 48, 98, 55, 100, 101, 54, 54, 98, 100, 56, 57, 54, 53, 52, 57, 54, 55, 97, 101, 101, 102, 49, 100, 53, 53, 55, 56, 49, 54, 0, 0
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, now I found that I will get an error complaining that the metadata of the video is wrong even I set everything right (the `17` key of the image and the `com.apple.quicktime.content.identifier` of the video)

Comment: JPEG seems fine since I have tested the JPEG file with other `.mov` file and they could work together

Comment: Can you upload both files?

Comment: sure, the image is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3gpxduffzu9861k/cf70b7de66bd89654967aeef1d557816.jpg?dl=0) and the video is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6dg1f7xjcs8iltl/cf70b7de66bd89654967aeef1d557816.mov?dl=0)

Comment: edited my answer above. How did you get the mov file to your computer? the key maybe got lost while exporting

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I think the metadata of `jpg` and `.mov` is just fine, you could see the `17` metadata of the jpg using [this](http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi) online tool (be noted to download the original image file rather than the preview one from the link I provide)

Comment: JPG metadata is fine, I think its the mov. Just noticed the mov duration is 15s - isnt that way to long for an live photo? Actually not sure about this.

Comment: Hate that apple didn't give any more information about this